# Best way to remove from map in short amount of time

Tags: java

I have this record

```
private static record BlockedPattern (Class<? extends Pattern> getClazz, Predicate<MyObject> getPredicate, long getActiveUntil) {}
```

which I store in a ConcurrentHashMap like this

```
private final Map<Class<? extends Pattern>, BlockedPattern> _patterns = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

My code executes for each object every 400 millisecond check using `isBlocked` method which check if time passed or predicate is false. Considering I can have 400-800 objects, this mean 800 checks per 400 ms and maybe more (Java 21). What is the best way to remove passed pattern or false predicate in `isBlocked` method?

Using removeIf, using iterator or what? I want the fastest option possible and light way.

Note: map can keep a maximum of 3 element. Not more since I have only 2-3 patterns.

removeIf and check if System.currentMillisecond() > getActiveUntil or !getPredicate.test()

Comment: Create a non-concurrent copy of the map, perform the operation there, then replace the old map?

Comment: Is this a bottleneck? 0.5 ms for a simple check seems like plenty of time.

Comment: If your map only contains 3 elements, you might get better performance with a 3-element array. Then you won't have the overhead of hashing.

Comment: 0.5 ms is the loop delay. Every 0.5 ms it goes though 900 object and perform isBlocked check.

Answer (score 0):

For high-performance and lightweight removal of objects based on a time condition and a predicate, you can use a combination of 'removeIf' and a custom removal condition. The use of iterators may not be necessary in this case.